# Background on leg stays after subtraction in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, computer-science

The picture on the left is my background image and the one on the right is the original image:

[image]

After doing subtraction,im having trouble in removing the background on the ankle:

[image]

The purpose is to get the foreground only, does anyone have an idea? Shown below is the code on how I carry out my background subtraction as well as display it. Thanks.

```
 I = (imread('frame9.jpg'));
 figure(1),imshow(I);
 bg =(imread('background.jpg'));
 figure(2),imshow(bg);
 Ip = bg-I;
 figure(3),imshow(Ip);
```

Comment: The difference between the jeans color and the black panel in the background is very little, hence you see it as a black stripe (which means values close to 0).

Comment: As Itay pointed out, you have to think in terms of grayscale, where dark blue is quite equal to black. Maybe you can perform the subtraction in each color channel R-G-B and see how the result comes out.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution is incomplete, but it can give you a lead:

I used the following operations to create a mask:

- Shrink images by factor of x2 in each axis (reduce some noise).
- Compute absolute difference of shrank images.
- Convert to binary image, using threshold (threshold is found using `graythresh`).
- Dilate binary image.
- Resize binary back to full size.
- Mask pixels from foreground image by multiplying it with binary mask.

Check the following code:

```
%Read two images from hosting site.
twoImages = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dN5O.png');

%Convet from uint8 to double (pixels range [0, 1])
twoImages = im2double(twoImages);

B = twoImages(7:332, 23:599, :);
I = twoImages(7:332, 706:1282, :);

%Shrink images by factor of x2 in each axis.
sB = imresize(B, 0.5);
sI = imresize(I, 0.5);

%Diference of shrank images.
sD = abs(sB - sI);

%Convert to binary image, using threshold.
level = graythresh(sD);
sBW = im2bw(sD, level);

%Dilate binary image
se = strel('disk', 6);
sBW = imdilate(sBW, se);

%Resize binary image to size of I (create binary mask).
BW = imresize(sBW, [size(I,1), size(I,2)]);

%Mask elements with BW = 0 (BW is used as mask).
I = I .* double(cat(3, BW, BW, BW));
figure;imshow(I);
```

Result:
[image]